# Classic ASP and Internet Explorer 7

Tags: asp-classic, internet-explorer-7

I have a page that produces more than 50,000 lines of code after it runs.

Although hard to believe (sarcasm), IE7 chokes up on it (gives me slow script warning), and of course IE6 is worse. I get errors on the page - but depending on what information I load the line number can be anything from the ASP to HTML to jQuery. I've separated these three and it just comes down to the size of the loops.

I tried using response.buffer/ response.flush throughout the page but that has not helped. It could be I'm using it wrong, but as far as I know response.buffer just needs to equal true- and response.flush just needs to be anywhere you need to not hold on information too long (i did both inside and outside of all loops- perhaps this is a no no?).

Short of splitting up the page into several web pages, is there anything else I could try?

**I have to develop for IE7 so no way around it unfortunately.**

Comment: Could you load some with AJAX and as you scroll down the page have more loaded?

Comment: @drummin yah, I guess I'll have to take another route. Was just hoping there was an easy out. :)